# JQuery Restricting Date Range Based on Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the JQuery DatePicker to have the user pick a date and have that show up in a textbox. Easy enough. However a restriction I'm working on is that the date range is restricted based on the month that's currently picked out in a user dropdown menu to the month beginning and end dates.

So for example if someone selects "Aug/2010" in the dropdown then the Datepicker for the textbox must be between August 1st and August 31st - the beginning and end of the month. This

Textbox outputted HTML:

```
<select id="ctl00_contentlocalnav_Menu_selectmonth">
    <option value="NA">-- Select Month --</option>
    <option value="Jun/2010">Jun/2010</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="May/2010">May/2010</option>
    <option value="Aug/2009">Aug/2009</option>
    <option value="Jul/2009">Jul/2009</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         $("#ctl00_contentactual_txtDate").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2010, 8 - 1, 1), maxDate: new Date(2010, 8 - 1, 31) });
     });
```

As you see the JQuery range is hard coded. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why aren't you allowing the year and month to be selected with datepicker as well?

If it's for convenience sake (large year range), then why do you need to restrict the user?

Comment: that's a good question - mostly it's out of convenice because that's the way I get data back out of the database.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more why a user is restricted to certain month and year pairs? If you need the month and year to get data from the database, could you not just get the month and year from the date selected and look to the database from there?

Comment: @Nate not sure I understand the question. I need the Month/Year pairs to get data back to the database so that's step 1. The next step is that the user might want to modify certain dates in the outputted data but he is restricted to that specific month/year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

Change the drop down values to contain a min/max date range that is able to be parsed by JavaScript.
For example:

```
<select id="ctl00_contentlocalnav_Menu_selectmonth">
    <option value="NA">-- Select Month --</option>
    <option value="06/01/2010-06/30/2010">Jun/2010</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="05/01/2010-05/31/2010">May/2010</option>
    <option value="08/01/2009-08/31/2009">Aug/2009</option>
    <option value="07/01/2009-07/31/2009">Jul/2009</option>
</select>
```

You can then bind to the `change` event of the drop down, and alter the date picker range.

```
$(function() {
    $('#ctl00_contentlocalnav_Menu_selectmonth').change(function() {
        var ranges = $(this).val().split('-');
        var minDate = new Date();
        minDate.setTime(Date.parse(ranges[0]));
        var maxDate = new Date();
        maxDate.setTime(Date.parse(ranges[1]));
        $("#ctl00_contentactual_txtDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        $("#ctl00_contentactual_txtDate").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
    });
});​
```

Comment: That's good, but I'm not able to change the value as it's actually an ASP dropdown control.

Comment: It's possible. I have done it in the past. If you provide some example code I can try to help you.